# How to delete org-mode table separator | quickly?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

If I have the following text:

`Name  Score
Bob    87 
Ted    99 
Mary   78`

I know C-c | will covert it to org table. But how can I do the other way around?

If I have a org table already, how can I convert it to text block?

I originally thought I could use multiple-cursor to delete, but this is not that effective if the table is huge.

Anyone any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `M-%`? (`query-replace`)

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717483/howto-convert-org-mode-table-to-original-tabbed-format). Note that `org-export-table` can convert org tables to several formats, but not in-place.

Comment: I found the procedure can also be quick: select a region, M-x replace string, | -> nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhat inspired by `org-table-transpose-table-at-point`:

```el
(defun org-table-strip-table-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((table (delete 'hline (org-table-to-lisp)))
     (contents (orgtbl-to-generic
            table '(:sep "\t"))))
    (goto-char (org-table-begin))
    (re-search-forward "|")
    (backward-char)
    (delete-region (point) (org-table-end))
    (insert contents)))
```